# Is there a way to generate code from a modeling project in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to generate code from a modeling project in VS2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following topic from the RC docs: [How to: Generate Files from a UML Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329480%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Also, see if this blog post by Tim Fischer helps: "[How To: Generate Code from Team System UML Diagrams in VS 2010 Team System Beta 2 (Update 4)](http://blogs.msdn.com/timfis/archive/2009/10/31/how-to-generate-code-from-uml-diagrams-in-vs-2010-team-system-beta-2.aspx)"

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this feature is coming, but not here yet in Beta2.

Ramesh Rajagopal of Microsoft [answering a similar question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsprerelease/thread/62eea855-af4a-4821-9843-3ef2377aebc2) in Aug 09.

- Similar post/response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269414/code-stubbing-with-visual-studio-2010-uml-modeling)