# Visual Studio UML 2010 code generation for methods or properties

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, uml, code-generation

I set up a visual studio 2010 UML modeling project and created a class diagram with several classes. The code generation works fine (I am using the code generation template delivered within the Visualization and Modeling Feature Pack for Visual Studio).
Whenever I click "Generate Code" on a class, I get a nice class stub including properties and method stubs for this class.

Now I am trying to add some custom code into a method of a class. The idea is to have every time I generate the code for the class the method would already have some code written in it (By default, the content of each method is "throw new Sytem.NotImplementedException()"). As far as I understand I first need to create a tt / t4 template. Then I need to set up in the class designer in the properties of the method the text template bindings - they should point to the newly created template. I tried it, but I can't figure out how to get this working. Or do I misunderstand a concept here? Any ideas?

And yes, I have read the msdn documentation about code generation and text templates, as well as Oleg Sych's blog. But neither of these did show me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you much because I don't have an MSDN subscription (see my answer for why this is related,) but may I ask what do you intend to do in your custom code generators?

Comment: I have a valid Visual Studio Ultimate Edition. The code generation works fine. But when I generate code I only get a very basic class - the generated methods for example are only stubs and don't have any code at all. I want to use the TT/T4 template bindings to fill these methods with some code when I start the code generation for my model.

Comment: Have you considered this question: [Code stubbing with Visual Studio 2010 UML modeling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269414/code-stubbing-with-visual-studio-2010-uml-modeling)

Answer (score 1):

Check this article out [How to: Generate Code from UML Class Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657795.aspx#custom): it says that you need to install a Visual Studio Feature Pack to get a Generate Code command in the UML items. You need an MSDN subscription to get that Feature Pack, as far as I can tell. So I couldn't try it out.

There is a section titled Customizing the Generated Code Command and it indeed suggests modifying the default T4 templates using in conjunction with the UML.
If I were you and I had no option to get the MSDN subscription I'd write an Add-in (or a VS extension) and process the UML file. That would require you to understand the inner working of the UML file to generate C# from UML.

Here's the UML of some *.classdiagram file. It is for a class that contains an attribute (field) and an operation. Is starting manually from here an option?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<logicalClassDesignerModel xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core" xmlns:dm1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/Kernel" xmlns:dm2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/Component" xmlns:dm3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/Activity" xmlns:dm4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/Interaction" xmlns:dm5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/UseCase" xmlns:dm6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/UmlModelLibrary" xmlns:dm7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/UmlDiagrams" xmlns:dm8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/ModelStore" dslVersion="1.0.0.0" Id="0b035e1e-cf78-4d7b-a9c5-7ae15e246642" name="UMLClassDiagram1" linkedPackageId="30fb2a44-daa7-48cf-a306-c91b92f1dd7b" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dsltools/LogicalClassDesigner">
  <packagedElements>
    <logicalClassDesignerModelHasTypes>
      <class Id="5d701b74-ed36-4baa-8318-0406964414ce" name="Class1" isAbstract="false" isLeaf="false" isActiveClass="false">
        <elementDefinition Id="82f92ae7-5d9b-4e64-8497-39c686ce2e5d" />
        <ownedAttributesInternal>
          <property Id="06827ace-592e-4cf7-bc13-946f073f2b73" name="Attribute2" isLeaf="false" isStatic="false" isReadOnly="false" isDerived="false" isDerivedUnion="false" aggregation="None" isComposite="false">
            <elementDefinition Id="3ebbef23-6573-42bf-8542-a3504f1ef28a" />
          </property>
        </ownedAttributesInternal>
        <ownedOperationsInternal>
          <operation Id="c061b4ea-9880-4674-8775-a7b360a2791d" name="Operation1" isLeaf="false" isStatic="false" isAbstract="false" concurrency="Sequential" isQuery="false">
            <elementDefinition Id="fe154244-f792-415d-8ebc-50d5e3a13362" />
            <ownedParameters>
              <operationHasOwnedParameters>
                <parameter Id="6cbf9775-608c-4a1c-bd17-14397c5ce0f3" direction="Return">
                  <elementDefinition Id="f9eabe6e-f42c-4ece-a0fc-6da2a5da11f0" />
                  <type_NamedElement>
                    <referencedTypeMoniker Id="7acb8bf9-6778-42b4-949c-5fbb1ed0a9bc" LastKnownName="String" />
                  </type_NamedElement>
                </parameter>
              </operationHasOwnedParameters>
            </ownedParameters>
          </operation>
        </ownedOperationsInternal>
      </class>
    </logicalClassDesignerModelHasTypes>
    <packageHasNamedElement>
      <referencedType Id="7acb8bf9-6778-42b4-949c-5fbb1ed0a9bc" name="String" isAbstract="false" isLeaf="false" cachedFullName="String">
        <elementDefinition Id="59259974-6d55-42c6-b7bd-763d77ac8ef9" />
      </referencedType>
    </packageHasNamedElement>
  </packagedElements>
  <package Id="30fb2a44-daa7-48cf-a306-c91b92f1dd7b" name="ModelingProject1">
    <elementDefinition Id="7c93d198-9011-4ef0-b6ba-9bd438a05ad5" />
    <profileInstances>
      <packageHasProfileInstances Id="d0a13992-851d-423d-916d-e1976a34f3f6">
        <profileInstance Id="c7f4eecf-37de-4fb2-b7fa-14747958e8cd" name="StandardProfileL2">
          <elementDefinition Id="e34d544e-0fea-4ed6-ac5e-1b74119ac791" />
        </profileInstance>
        <elementDefinition Id="0caec977-1f8c-4ba3-a7db-8cc9ad9cc73b" />
      </packageHasProfileInstances>
      <packageHasProfileInstances Id="3b4e12c7-adee-45b2-a675-bca964c11f99">
        <profileInstance Id="c9e7d01a-6aa0-4697-8877-cdafc408d6ca" name="StandardProfileL3">
          <elementDefinition Id="532ea607-fb19-44b8-8502-3351b05452be" />
        </profileInstance>
        <elementDefinition Id="29349502-908c-4fda-9054-c48619c59ed0" />
      </packageHasProfileInstances>
    </profileInstances>
  </package>
</logicalClassDesignerModel>
```

Comment: The Visual Feature Pack is installed on my machine. Also I have a valid license for the Visual Studio Ultimate Edition. All the necessary products are installed on my computer. The code generation works fine. But I only get a very basic class - the generated methods for example don't have any code at all. I want to use the TT/T4 template bindings to fill these methods with some code when I start the code generation for my model.

Comment: The very basic class you get is generated using a default T4 file. The link I posted (how to generate code from UML, above) contains information on how to get the default T4 files and customize them to suit your needs. Does that help you? What you're doing is very interesting btw.