# Possible to do UML Diagrams in Visual C# and then have code generated from it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uml

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 RC. Would it be possible that after doing my UML Diagrams, I could then generate classes with method stubs from it?

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892105/is-there-a-way-to-generate-code-from-a-modeling-project-in-vs2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has stated that they intend to extend VS Architect edition to include code generation through the use of plugins but it is not available at this point.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/thread/62eea855-af4a-4821-9843-3ef2377aebc2

Heres an article adding code generation to VS 2010 yourself:
http://www.olegsych.com/2010/01/uml-modeling-and-code-generation-in-visual-studio-2010/

Theres a plug in for VS here:
http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/sde/vs/

Here are some standalone tools:
http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-code-generation.html
http://www.tangiblearchitect.net/visual-studio/

Answer (score 1):

Have you found the built-in class designer? Its pretty much UML compliant, and very easy to use.

Quick Start: Add a class, use View|Class View, richt-click the class and "Show in Diagram"

But no other diagram types.

Comment: I can see I can do that for already created classes. But isn't it possible to first do all the UML Diagram and then click in a button and have it generate all the classes in several files?

Comment: You can start with an empty diagram (Add new item). Code is generated and changed continuously. You can alternate working in code and in the diagram.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288743(VS.71).aspx  Yep, can create classes in the designer.

Comment: Hm , I see. Too bad it seems to be always crashing when I try to create new methods/properties :(